# How to solve this graphing question?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$ \frac{|x-2|} {(x^2-4)}+\frac{(x-2)} {|x-2|} = b $

determine for which values of $b$ the equation  has one and only solution.

I tried sketching the graph, but was unable to do so accuratly...also, I cannot see any feasible way of solving it algebracly...

Any help?

Comment: Note that the second term is just $sgn(x-2)$ and the first term is $\frac {sgn(x-2)}{x+2}$

Comment: @Ragnar. I have the feeling that it is a bit more complex. Do you agree ? Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Am I missing something? Sketching those graphs shouldn't be to hard, knowing the definition of the signum function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function

Comment: @Ragnar. Not too hard, I totally agree if one takes into account everything told in the very good link you provide.  Cheers :)

Comment: And just observe too that there are "holes" in the domain at $\pm 2$. For $x\neq\pm 2$, we have $y=(1+\frac{1}{x+2})\operatorname{sgn}(x-2)$.

Comment: I think it might be straight forward to consider the cases when $x>2$, $x<2$ and $x=2$

Answer (score 0):

What is the range of your function in the domain $x>2$?  It is monotonic.

What is the range of your function in the domain $x<2$?  It is monotonic for both $x<-2$ and $-2<x<2$.

What values $b$ appear in exactly one of the ranges?

Comment: you need to draw it mate....